# find in directory that starts with dash

Tags: unix, shell, find, escaping

`find` interprets a dash at the start of a filename as the start of an option. Using the familiar `--` trick doesn't work since options are after the filename, quoting has no effect, and replacing the first dash with `\-` doesn't work either. Users are often encouraged to precede such filenames with `./`, but what can I do if I don't know whether the given path will be absolute or relative?

Edit: One solution is to `find "$(readlink -f -- "$test_filename")"`, but it's ugly. Any better ideas?

**Edit 2**: Thanks for the suggestions. Here are the two scripts that resulted from this effort:  [safe-find.sh](https://gist.github.com/716763); [safe-count-files.sh](https://gist.github.com/716802)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may seem a bit cheap, but I actually recommend the `readlink` workaround that you've figured out. According to the [Unix standard](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html),

> The first argument that starts with a
>   '-' (...) and all subsequent arguments
>   shall be interpreted as an
>   *expression*

so `--` will indeed not work. thkala's solution may also work, but I find it less readable. It may be faster though, if you're doing a lot of `find` invocations.

Comment: My answer before the OP's edit would have indeed involved readlink because it is indeed less esoteric than my first oneliner. It's one disadvantage is that it launches two more processes (a forked shell and readlink itself) and that if you have multiple directories as arguments to find, applying readlink to all of them will require at least a loop and some trickery.

Comment: @thkala: I just figured that out myself. `$(exec readlink -f -- "$file")` prevents one of the forks, at the expense of readability.

Comment: @larsmans: thkala's answer has the advantage of working on systems that don't have `readlink -f` (only GNU, NetBSD and OpenBSD have it).

Comment: @Gilles: MacOS X 10.6.4 has `readlink` from GNU. Does thkala's solution also work with the NetBSD shell (`ash`)? I checked that it works in the Korn Shell.

Comment: @larsmans: thkala's first solution requires the `[[ … ]]` construct (so bash/ksh/zsh), and the second solution requires `${…/…/…}` (so bash/ksh93/zsh). According to the [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/readlink.1.html), OSX 10.6.4 doesn't have `readlink -f` (it has the [FreeBSD `readlink`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=readlink&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE&format=html)).

Comment: @Gilles, excuse me, I didn't notice I was typing to a Linux box though `ssh` *blush*

Answer (score 6):

If it is in a script you can always check for it. E.g. for bash, ksh or zsh:

```
if [[ "$DIR" = -* ]]; then
    find ./"$DIR"
else
    find "$DIR"
fi
```

In a more terse form (for bash, ksh93 or zsh):

```
find "${DIR/#-/./-}"
```

You can even do this with the parameters of a script, if they are all supposed to be directories:

```
find "${@/#-/./-}"
```

Comment: Note that `if [ "$DIR = -* ]` would either match `DIR` to the literal string `-*` (if there are no files whose name begins with `-` in the current directory) or likely cause a syntax error (if there are).

Comment: @Gilles: true... I don't know what came over me - I never use 'test' or [ in bash.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way that should work on all Unix-like systems, with no requirement on a specific shell or on a non-standard utility¹.

```
case $DIR in
  -*) DIR=./$DIR;;
esac
find "$DIR" …
```

If you have a list of directories in your positional parameters and want to process them, it gets a little complicated. Here's a POSIX sh solution:

```
i=1
while [ $i -le $# ]; do
  case $1 in
    -*) x=./$1;;
    *) x=$1;;
  esac
  set -- "$@" "$x"
  shift
  i=$(($i + 1))
done
find "$@" …
```

Bourne shells and other pre-POSIX sh implementations lack arithmetic and `set --`, so it's a little uglier.

```
i=1
while [ $i -le $# ]; do
  x=$1
  case $1 in
    -*) x=./$1;;
  esac
  set a "$@" "$x"
  shift
  shift
  i=`expr $i + 1`
done
find "$@" …
```

¹ 
<sub>`readlink -f` is available on GNU (Linux, Cygwin, etc.), NetBSD ≥4.0, OpenBSD ≥2.2, BusyBox. It is not available (unless you've installed GNU tools, and you've made sure they're in your `PATH`) on Mac OS X (as of 10.6.4), HP-UX (as of 11.22), Solaris (as of OpenSolaris 200906), AIX (as of 7.1).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Use a glob to capture the dash:

```
find . -name '[-]*'
```

---

edit: updated to remove the phrase regular expression, and to quote the glob so it's interpreted by find, not bash (only affects some edge cases).

Comment: That's globbing, not a regex.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson It may be globbing, but it's also definitely a regex. There's a (trivial) character class, there's catenation, and there's a Kleene star. If the character class had one more character, there'd be alternation, and it would have all the things. However, I will grant that, technically, any series of characters is a regular expression if you use it as one.

Comment: @ParthianShot: The shell processes all of `[-]*` as a glob, not a regular expression. The asterisk here is not a Kleene star since it doesn't mean "zero or more". In a glob it means "anything" as a wild card. Here the expression means a hyphen followed by any sequence rather than zero or more hyphens. It should be quoted, however, in order to prevent premature expansion.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Oh, I know that bit. I was just being pedantic; pointing out that it _can_ be interpreted as a valid regex, unlike some globs. For example, `*` on its own is a syntax error in a regex, while in a glob it's valid. That having been said, upvoting your comment since it is pertinent and could be helpful to someone stumbling across this answer.