# Bash regex to match a "./" at the start of a line? OR renaming files with a leading "-"

Tags: regex, perl, bash, rename

I'm trying to rename files with spaces and other such script breaking characters in them.

The platform is Ubuntu server 12 (with Bash 4) and any instance of the 'rename' command refers to Prename aka Perl Rename.

I'm either having a problem writing a suitable regex, or I'm having a problem creating a valid variable from the find command.

Here's my maturely named test data (all files, no directories):

```
/test/-poop
/test/poopfile.txt
/test/po_________!!!!!!!! $$^^^   op.sh
```

(EDIT) Expected output: I want to change the filenames to

```
/test/poop
/test/poopfile.txt
/test/po_op.sh
```

(/EDIT)

If I run this command in /test:

```
find * -type f -exec rename -n 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_.]/_/g; s/_+/_/g' {} \;
```

I of course get:

```
find: unknown predicate `-poop'
```

So I changed things: (find * -> find . so that the results of the find command are prefixed with ./)

```
find . -type f -exec rename -n 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_.]/_/g; s/_+/_/g' {} \;
```

Which returns

```
./-poop renamed as ._-poop
./poopfile.txt as ._poopfile.txt
./po_________!!!!!!!! $$^^^   op.sh renamed as ._po_op.sh
```

That's no good. All my files are now prefixed _ because my regex did exactly what I told it to.  If I didn't have to cope with files that had a leading "-" then I'd be fine, but that's exactly the kind of thing I'm trying to treat with this script.

This is where I'm stuck - I can't figure out how to get my regex to *not* match either the first two characters in a line, or the first instance of "./"

```
^.{2} ## matches the first two characters in the string
^./   ## matches the ./ at the start of the line (assuming I change my delimiter from /)
```

But how do I say "Anything that is NOT the first two characters in the string and is NOT a character in [a-zA-Z0-9.-_]?"

OR

Am I doing this entirely wrong? Is there a way that I can pass the results of the find command to the rename script so that a leading "-" does not cause find to barf?

Actually thinking on those lines - I wrote this:

```
for f in $( find . -type f ); do
    p=$( printf "%s\n" "$f" | sed 's/^..//' );
    rename -n 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_.]/_/g; s/_+/_/g' "$p";
done
```

Result:

```
Unknown option: p
Unknown option: o
Unknown option: o
Unknown option: p
Usage: rename [-v] [-n] [-f] perlexpr [filenames]
```

So even if I can get find to hand "-poop" to rename as "-poop" it's still barfing on the leading hyphen.

Pretty sure the answer lies in the regex.

I'm very grateful for any guidance that can be offered! This is my first question here - please let me know if I've made mistakes or etiquette errors. I'm very aware that my knowledge of regex is poor, but I think I've reached the point on this where not asking a question would be the silly course of action.

Comment: Have you tried `rename -n -- $regex $filenames`? `--` is a widely used method of saying "options end here, filenames start here". [`find` itself doesn't support it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286073/find-in-directory-that-starts-with-dash), but `rename` might.

Comment: Can you give us the exact expected output for the three test files?

Comment: It does not solve your problem but, for information, the `-` hyphen to match a literal hyphen is normally put first or last in a regular expression's character class, as in `[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]`.  Otherwise, the hyphen may be interpreted as the operator of a character range, as in `[A-Z]`.

Comment: Hove you tried mv(1) (a.k.a. 'move')?  rename is the UNIX C interface, or the Windows command-line program.

Comment: @DCoder - YES! rename does work with -- . I can work with that, thankyou!

Comment: @Edu - That was remiss of me: Expected output should be: `-poop renamed as -poop` and
`po_________!!!!!!!! $$^^^   op.sh renamed as po_op.sh` . pooptest.txt should be untouched as it does not contain characters outside [a-zA-Z0-9-_]

Comment: @DCoder:  (If you made your comment an answer, I would upvote it.)

Comment: @cdarke - In this question rename refers to a perl script that ships with Ubuntu and I believe a few other linux distros. See http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/prename/

Comment: @thb: [done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10798757/1233508).

Comment: https://socialtext.net/perl5/prename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rename -n -- $regex $filenames`.

The key here is `--`, which is a widely used method of saying "options end here, filenames start here". [`find` itself doesn't support it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286073/find-in-directory-that-starts-with-dash), but `rename` does.

[Some more details here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean)